# python generator returning ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, generator

I'm having the following odd behavior with a generator that returns a numpy array. In the real application, I am using scipy.sparse to implement an iterative linear algebra solver: The below is a stripped down version. I have the following:

```
import numpy as np

def iterable(n):

  nc = np.array([0,0,0])
  yield nc

  while nc[0] < n:
    nc += 1
    yield nc

  raise StopIteration
```

When i try and populate a list with the output

```
iter = iterable(4)

print list(iter)
```

I get

```
$ python itertest.py 
[array([4, 4, 4]), array([4, 4, 4]), array([4, 4, 4]), array([4, 4, 4]), array([4, 4, 4])]
```

i.e., the result of the final 'yield' repeated n times. If I change the `yield nc` to `yield nc.tolist()` then I get the expected result. If possible I would like to avoid that as I will end up having to re-make the array. What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only create one ndarray.  When you do `nc += 1`, you modify it *in place*.  So the later iterations modify the same array already yielded, and then yield it again.

You can see this by printing out the generated arrays one at a time:

```
>>> it = iterable(3)
>>> x = next(it)
>>> print x
[0 0 0]
>>> y = next(it)
>>> print y
[1 1 1]
>>> print x   # x changed!
[1 1 1]
>>> x is y
True
```

You can see that the second iteration changes the object that was yielded on the first iteration, because they are the same object.

To fix it, change your `nc += 1` line to `nc = nc + 1`.  This will create a new array on each iteration.